Pulumi: Possible to get a resource and update it without importing?
I'm using Pulumi to manage some resources in AWS. This really applies to ANY resource created with pulumi but I'll use a security group for this example:
There is a database-sg security group which is the security group for the databases and is managed by the DBA team (who does not use Pulumi). I have a security group ecs-sg that is used for some ECS services. The pulumi script creates the ecs-sg, but then I need to add that to the database-sg for allowed inbound. I know I can just get the database security group, but I haven't seen a way to update it afterwards without using pulumi import to import the database security group (which would then mean I control the entire thing).
Am I missing something? Is there some way to get the database-sg security group and then simply add the ecs-sg to the inbound rules?
My pulumi script to create the ecs-sg (if it matters):
ecs-sg = aws.ec2.SecurityGroup("ecs-sg",
     name="ECS Security Group"
     description="Security Group for managing ECS services",
     vpcid=vpc.id,
     egress=[
       aws.ec2.SecurityGroupEgressArgs(
         protocol="-1",
         from_port=0,
         to_port=0,
         cidr_blocks=["0.0.0.0/0"]
       ),
     ]
)

Code to get the database-sg but I don't know how to add to this afterwards.
database_sg = aws.ec2.get_security_group(id="sg-XXXXXXXXX")

